# Bootstrap datetime picker positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added datetime picker plugin in my code. It works but not positioning rightly. When I focused on the input it's showed in footer of page not near the input. What should I check for?

```js
 $(".form-date").datetimepicker({
   format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
   minView: 2,
   maxView: 4,
   autoclose: true,
   language: 'tr',
   pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="Tarih" class="col-md-3 control-label">Tarih</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 input-append date form-date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Tarih" id="Tarih" value="" placeholder="Tarih">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this - https://jsfiddle.net/3L4gc6fy/1/

Comment: you needed an option `widgetPositioning` or visite link: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning

Answer (score 2):

Aside from missing some of the required assets (datetimepicker, moment, etc) in your shared snippet, you are using deprecated options which prevent datepicker from displaying.

You can find [**current options here**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/).

[List of required assets here.](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

Update to the following:

- `format: 'dd.MM.YYYY'`
- `min` & `maxView` are gone but you can check `viewMode` on the options link (no min-max option though).
- `autoclose` to `keepOpen` (although it's set to `false` by default, so no
  need)
- `language` to `locale: 'tr'`
- `pickerPosition` to `widgetPositioning {horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}` object.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$('.form-date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd.MM.YYYY',
  locale: 'tr',
  widgetPositioning: {
    horizontal: 'left',
    vertical: 'bottom'
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Tarih" class="col-md-3 control-label">Tarih</label>
    <div class='input-group date form-date col-md-9 input-append'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Tarih" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no 'pickerPosition: "bottom-left"' option for Bootstrap Datetime Picker.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

May be it is causing the problems.

Comment: No it's ok: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php?utm_source=siteweb&utm_medium=demo&utm_campaign=Site%2BWeb#demo_position

Answer (score 0):

There is no datetimepicker component files in your html reference codes. You should have added js and css files.

First download the scripts from [the component website](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) here or clone from git:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker.git
```

And add references in the head section:

**Sources:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="dtp_input2" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date Picking</label>
            <div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" /><br/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for older version of Bootstrap Datetime Picker. But you can change the positioning by applying **CSS** to the dropdown picker.

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
    inset: auto!important;
}
```

Here is the docs for more details :
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/